# jsonpickle does not apply unpickable to the nested object

Tags: python, jsonpickle

I would like to use jsonpickle to serialise my complex object with unpicklable=False. However, the unpicklable only applies to the first object, rather than the nested one.

I have the following object to serialise

```
T = TypeVar('T')

class Result(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, is_success: bool, payload: T = None, error: Error = None):
        self.isSuccess: bool = is_success
        if is_success:
            self.successPayload: T = payload
        else:
            self.failedPayload: Error = error
```

And the nested object `T` is

```
class Coordinate:
    def __init__(self, coordinate):
        self.coordinate= coordinate
```

The result of `jsonpickle.encode(result, unpicklable=False)` is

```
{"isSuccess": true, "successPayload": {"coordinate": {"dtype": "float64", "values": [-0.4022799336814849, 0.8902557877735706, -0.17517361570654688]}}, "__orig_class__": {"_inst": true, "_special": false, "_name": null, "__origin__": {"py/type": "toolbox.model.result.Result"}, "__args__": [{"py/type": "Coordinate"}], "__parameters__": [], "__slots__": null, "__module__": "toolbox.model.result"}
```

Can anyone please give some advice how to remove fields, such as `__orig_class__`, from the nested object?

Thank you